# Missing Basic C++ Libraries

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm currently having a number of issues accessing basic c++ libraries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int arbitrary(){
    std::string why;
    string fail;
    return 0; 
}

int main(){
    arbitrary(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Atom's linter package has alerted me to a number of strange errors having to do with the code above (which exists in a single cpp file without any accompanying .h). The program is obviously a pretty meaningless one which I'm using to illustrate the errors I'm getting. In short:

- < iostream > is not recognized as a file or directory, nor is iostream.h
- < string > is not recognized either (though I've tried string.h and that is recognized)
- However, even when string.h is successfully included the string variable type on line 9 is listed as undeclared (i.e. the 'string' applied to the variable 'fail').
- String is listed as a non-member of std.

I've tried compiling from windows terminal with g++ and I get the same set of incongruous errors. I'm thinking somehow things aren't compiling quite the way they should or perhaps I'm missing some files. Any thoughts on how I might be able to approach the issue? I have the latest version of MinGW installed.

Comment: Please post the exact command line that you are using.

Comment: `string.h` is a C header, and has nothing to do with this. Are you sure you have installed the C++ standard library with the compiler?

Comment: We cannot possibly diagnose this without knowing how you've [mis]installed your toolchain. :)

Comment: I thought I had installed the standard library but perhaps I'm wrong. The MinGW installation seemed fairly straightforward. Is there an easy way you know of to check that out on Windows? Command line compile: g++ -o test "c++_test_file.cpp" results in multiple errors corresponding to the ones I've described.

Comment: What toolchain information might I provide to help? Admittedly I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking of me...

Comment: Update: I realized I had installed MinGW32 and my machine is 64 bit. After installing the 32/64 bit version, things are running fine in the command line but atom's linter is still confused about errors. Thanks for the help nonetheless, I'm guessing I can figure out how to get where I need to go from here.